# Get the country of a coordinate using basemap and shapefiles

Tags: python, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I want a Python function that given a lat/lon returns the country. I want to use basemap and shapefile but I'm not sure which shapefile(s) to use or how to check if a point is within a country. I'm focusing in European countries so I have downloaded NUTS 2013 shape file from [here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts).

How should I read and get the country of a lat/lon?

Comment: You are looking for "reverse geocoding", there are a few providers such as Nominatim (OpenStreetMap), Bing, Google and others

Comment: I want an offline solution, I just want to check if a given coordinate is in US or not.

Comment: Are you working with any particular Python libraries yet, like Shapely?

Comment: yeah, Shapely and Pyshp.